# How to use a form with autocomplete fields in django admin update action

Tags: django, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I am using a custom form in admin panel with two autocomplete fields among the others.

**My problem is that I don't know how to use the form in update action in order the stored data to appear with the autocomplete functionality.**

In my implementation in update action the values appearing without autocomplete functionality.

How can I fix that?

my form

```
class ModelSeoMetadatumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = ModelChoiceField(
        required=False, 
        queryset=MetaTag.objects.exclude(name__isnull=True).values_list('name', flat=True).distinct(), 
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='seo:name-autocomplete')
    )

    property = ModelChoiceField(
        required=False, 
        queryset=MetaTag.objects.exclude(property__isnull=True).values_list('property', flat=True).distinct(), 
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='seo:property-autocomplete')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ModelSeoMetadatum
        fields = ('name', 'content', 'property', 'content_type', 'object_id')
```

my admin

```
@admin.register(ModelSeoMetadatum)
class ModelSeoMetadatumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form  = ModelSeoMetadatumForm
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'content', 'property', 'content_object')
    fields = ('name', 'content', 'property', 'content_type', 'object_id')


    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        defaults = {}
        if obj is None:
            defaults['form'] = self.add_form
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting with this same problem myself for quite some time.

It didn't work until I found out that from Django 3.2 on, instead of `MyModel._meta.get_field('some_lookup_field').remote_field` you needed to pass to `AutocompleteSelect` `MyModel._meta.get_field('some_lookup_field')`

So without the `.remote_field`

So for me :

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'some_lookup_field': AutocompleteSelect(
                MyModel._meta.get_field('some_lookup_field'),
                admin.site,
                attrs={'style': 'width: 20em'},
            ),
        }
```

works just fine

Answer (score -1):

You should overwrite the widget and give it the admin site as parameter.

admin class:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```

form definition:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'some_lookup_field': AutocompleteSelect(
                MyModel._meta.get_field('some_lookup_field').remote_field,
                admin.site,
                attrs={'style': 'width: 20em'},
            ),
        }
```

Note, you need to have at lease one search_filter in the admin definition of your lookup field.

Have a look here for an improved version that expands if needed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55344987/how-to-filter-modeladmin-autocomplete-fields-results-with-the-context-of-limit-c/55476825#55476825)